# Execute MySQL query that access separate databases in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a MySQL query that accesses 2 databases. I am using Python to execute the query. The problem with Python MySQL connection is that it connects to a single database at any one time like below;

```
DbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='MySQLDatabase')
```

How can I get Python to execute a query that access 2 databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can qualify table names with the names of databases.  For example, if you specify a database `db1` when you establish the connection to the server, but you want to execute a query involving a table in another database `db2`, simply do something like:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', db='db1')
c = conn.cursor() 
c.execute("SELECT * FROM foo JOIN db2.bar")
```

Note also that it's not the case that you need to specify a database when setting up a connection.  If you do omit the database, you need to qualify every table name with the name of a database:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM db1.foo JOIN db2.bar")
```